# First line of every file in a new file

Tags: file, bash, shell, scripting, line

How can I get the first line of EVERY file in a directory and save them all in a new file?

```
#!/bin/bash

rm FIRSTLINE
for file in "$(find $1 -type f)";
do
head -1 $file >> FIRSTLINE
done
cat FIRSTLINE
```

This is my bash script, but when I do this and I open the file FIRSTLINE,
then I see this:

```
==> 'path of the file' <==
'first line' of the file
```

and this for all the files in my argument.

Does anybody has some solution?

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type f -exec head -1 \{\} \; > YOURFILE
```

might work for you.

Comment: Definitely the best answer. This also takes all files in subdirectories, recursively. If you only want the files in your current directory (non-recursively), you could also use the faster `head -qn1 * 2> /dev/null > YOURFILE`.

Comment: Escaping the `{` is not necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's true for every single `find` version @WilliamPursell ... but the escaping does not hurt.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `find`.  That portion of the string is parsed by the shell.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've quoted the output of `find` so it gets treated as a single string, so the `for` loop only runs once, with a single argument containing all the files. That means you run `head -1 file1 file2 file3 file4 ...` etc. and when given multiple files `head` prints the `==> file1 <==` headers.

So to fix it, remove the double quotes around the `find` shell-out, which ensures you run the `for` loop once for each file, as intended. Also, the semi-colon after the shell-out is unnecessary.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm FIRSTLINE
for file in $(find $1 -type f)
do
    head -1 $file >> FIRSTLINE
done
cat FIRSTLINE
```

This has some style issues though, do you really need to write to a file then `cat` the file to stdout? You could just print the output to stdout:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find $1 -type f)
do
    head -1 $file
done
```

Personally I'd write it like this:

```
find $1 -type f | xargs -L1 head -1
```

or if you need the output in the file and printed to stdout:

```
find $1 -type f | xargs -L1 head -1 | tee FIRSTLINE
```

Comment: +1 for a thorough explanation.  Still see also Zsolt's one-liner for a common, concise, popular alternative.

Comment: I strongly dislike `find`'s `-exec` option, `xargs` doesn't need the `\{\} \;` noise and in some cases is far more efficient because it doesn't need to fork a new process for every file (but when using `xargs -L1` it does need to)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ for file in $(find $1 -type f); do echo ''; 
    echo $file; 
    head -n 4 $file; 
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

for gzip files fo instances:

```
for file in `ls *.gz`; do gzcat $file | head -n 1; done > toto.txt
```